# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension while installing karafka-rdkafka 0.14.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Update karfka gem version 1.4 to `gem 'karafka', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'`
Then run bundle install facing issue on Windows machine

```
An error occurred while installing karafka-rdkafka (0.14.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  karafka was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
    waterdrop was resolved to 2.6.13, which depends on
      karafka-core was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
        karafka-rdkafka
```

Answer (score 0):

update your dependencies by the following command:

```
gem update --system
gem update
```

Comment: Still same error

Answer (score 0):

Is it windows or WSL? karafka-rdkafka as well as rdkafka-ruby do not work on Windows outside of WSL.

Comment: windows os it works with other windows. only facing this issue in my local system

Comment: It is not fully intended to work on windows outside of WSL or at least I do not support if officially (maintainer here). If your problem persists on WSL, please open an appropriate issue in the GH repo.